# Alternating arithmetic progression sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

A normal arithmetic sequence is characterized by a first number $a_1$ and a progression number $d$ which together gives the $a_n$ term by $a_1+(n-1)d$.

But I was working on some project and i met an alternating type of arithmetic sequence, that is instead of one progression number $d$, it has different progression terms that differ with $n$, giving a sequence like the following;

$a_1=a_1, $

$a_2=a_1+d_1, $

$a_3=a_1+d_1+d_2, $

$a_4=a_1+d_1+d_2+d_3, $

$a_5=a_1+2d_1+d_2+d_3, $

$a_6=a_1+2d_1+2d_2+d_3, $

$a_7=a_1+2d_1+2d_2+2d_3, $

$a_8=a_1+3d_1+2d_2+2d_3,...$

What is the formula for the $n$th term? Are there any references to such a sequence ?

Comment: Can you give the actual definition of your alternating sequence?

Comment: @donaastor I just edited my post to make the sequence more clear mate

Comment: It looks as though you have three arithmetic progressions interleaved each having the same common difference $d_1+d_2+d_3$.  Any three progressions with the same common difference could be interleaved in this way with an appropriate choice of the $d_i$. Alternatively you might analyse it by first summing the terms in threes and creating a single arithmetic progression with common difference $3(d_1+d_2+d_3)$.

Comment: @MarkBennet how is this going to give me the $n$th term?

Comment: I think after deleting the 1st term and rename the the sequence starting with a+d_1 and check each of n mod 3 we get the original sequences n+1 th term.

Comment: We can even generalized this d1,d2,....,dm for all positive integer m>2

Comment: For example $a_{10}=a_1+3d_1+3d_2+3d_3$

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas but this isn't going to work well in calculations...I just need a simple equation for a_n

Comment: $a_{11}=a_1+4d_1+3d_2+3d_3$

Comment: I think you are getting close to $a_n$

Comment: Well I left that to you - there are fancy ways to do it (eg using cube roots of unity), but simpler to analyse each progression separately and give the rules for $a_{3r}, a_{3r+1}, a_{3r+2}$ separately. If you know about cube roots of unity you might then be able to work out how to use $\omega^k+\bar \omega^k+1^k$ for appropriate k to create a formula which picks out the correct terms - but why be that complicated?

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm not really understanding what you are saying, but I get sense from it, can you please give a detailed way....its possibly an answer if it gives $a_n$ by a simple calculation

Comment: then we have $a_{13}=a_1+4(d_1+d_2+d_3) $ definitely a pattern , Thus $a_{3k+1}=a_1+k(d_1+d_2+d_3)$ NEXT WEIGHTS ARE K+1 , K , K AND NEXT WEGIHT IS K+1,K+1 ,K this is mod 3 fold that's what I mean in my previous comment

Comment: Well I can say, for example, that $a_{3r+1}=a_1+r\cdot (d_1+d_2+d_3)$ which is a simple arithmetic progression. You should be able to identify $a_{3r+2}$ and $a_{3r+3}$ in a similar way.